# Connect to a remote Oracle 11g server using OracleClient of .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, oracle11g

I have to connect to a Oracle server on the network using a .NET / C# (Winform) application. I am trying to use `System.Data.OracleClient` but in vain.

Here are the details I can possibly think of (that might help someone reading this question):

Platform: Visual Studio 2005 / .NET 2.0 with C# on Windows Vista Home Premium

Library:  `System.Data.OracleClient`

Server:   Oracle 11g (located on the same LAN)

Please note that I don't have Oracle installed locally and I have hunted every discussion forum possible for help - but most of them assume local Oracle installation!

Here is my connection string:

"`User Id=TSUSER;Password=ts12TS;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=`**MyServerIP**`)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));`"

And I get this error:

```
OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.
```

**Stack trace:**

`at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle..ctor(OciHandle parentHandle, HTYPE handleType, MODE ocimode, HANDLEFLAG handleflags)
    at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
    at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
    at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
    at DGKit.Util.DataUtil.Generate() in D:\SVNRoot\sandbox\DGDev\Util\DataUtil.cs:line 68`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working since 2 years on an ASP.NET 4.0 application that connects to Oracle, I still have to say that I hate it :-)

The Oracle .NET drivers are just awfully buggy. After tring several different versions (x86, x84, beta, stable, etc.) I finally found a solution that works.

I also experienced that the Oracle provider that ships (shipped?) with .NET itself was not usable for me, so only the .NET drivers/libraries directly from the Oracle site worked.

In addition, when having SQL Developer (the Java application) successfully running, it was by no means an indicator whether the .NET stuff works, too. It seems they are completely unrelated.

Comment: In addition to OracleClient from Microsoft (which I believe does not support Oracle 11g), I have tried with MSDAORA and Odbc / Oledb as well - it did not work.

I have also downloaded ODP.NET (ODAC 11.2) from Oracle site. The documentation of ODP.NET tells me that I need to have a local Oracle installation.

Is there any way I can connect to a remote Oracle server (on the LAN of course) using .NET / C#?

Comment: I ended up with an ODP.NET beta driver for 32-bit (version 2.112.1.1) "Oracle.DataAccess.dll". This works for _me_, but I doubt it will 1:1 work for you. Just try different versions, until everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Oracle client software installed? Can you connect using SQL+ on the client machine or using the server explorer?

Comment: I do not have SQL+ installed on local machine. Instead, I have Navicat Lite, using which I am able to connect to the Oracle server

Comment: I suspect that's your problem. The MS and Oracle data providers require the Oracle client software to be installed.